# Symfony2 Error : looks like something went wrong

Tags: symfony

I got this error while I accepted for not logging 
InvalidArgumentException:

> The file cache.xml does not exist (in:
>   C:\wamp\www\HelloWorld\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config).

I use Netbeans 
and I don't know how o resolve it such I have the cashe.xml file in the right way

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependency injection file at *[YourBundleName]/DependencyInjection/[YourBundleName]Extension.php*. The `load` function shoul look something like this:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('cache.xml');
   ...
}
```